# Router component rendering twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**Login** or **Register** component is rendering twice after redirect from **Home** component, i used `Navigate` to redirect routes in **PrivateRoute** component,i think that error is coming from router, i don't know where the problem, i checked every line of code [image: Router component rendering twice]

My index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import store from "./state/store";
import "./styles/index.scss";

const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
);
```

App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home, Login, Register } from "./pages";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function App() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route
                path="/"
                element={
                    <PrivateRoute>
                        <Home />
                    </PrivateRoute>
                }
            />
            <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
    );
}
const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
    const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
    return user ? children : <Navigate to="/login" replace={true} />;
};
const NotFound = () => <div>Not Found</div>;
```

login.js

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { login } from "../state/userSlice";
import { setToken } from "../utils/storage";
import Layout from "../components/layout";

export default function Login() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
    const handleLogin = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { email, password } = e.target;
        await axios
            .post("/api/v1/auth/login", {
                email: email.value,
                password: password.value,
            })
            .then((res) => {
                const { accessToken, refreshToken } = res.data;
                dispatch(login(jwt_decode(accessToken)));
                setToken(accessToken);
                setToken(refreshToken, "refreshToken");
                navigate("/");
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };
    return (
        <Layout>
            <div>
                <form method="post" onSubmit={handleLogin} className="form">
                    <div className="input__wrapper">
                        <input
                            placeholder="email@site.com"
                            type="email"
                            name="email"
                            className="form__input"
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="input__wrapper">
                        <input
                            placeholder="pass****"
                            type="password"
                            name="password"
                            className="form__input"
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                            login
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

register.js

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Layout from "../components/layout";

export default function Register() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const register = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { fname, lname, email, username, password } = e.target;
        await axios
            .post("/api/v1/auth/register", {
                fname: fname.value,
                lname: lname.value,
                username: username.value,
                email: email.value,
                password: password.value,
            })
            .then((res) => {
                navigate("/login");
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };
    return (
        <Layout>
            <div>
                <form method="post" onSubmit={register} className="form">
                    <div className="input__wrapper">
                        <input
                            placeholder="first name"
                            type="text"
                            name="fname"
                            className="form__input"
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="input__wrapper">
                        <input
                            placeholder="last name"
                            type="text"
                            name="lname"
                            className="form__input"
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="input__wrapper">
                        <input
                            placeholder="username"
                            type="text"
                            name="username"
                            className="form__input"
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="input__wrapper">
                        <input
                            placeholder="email@site.com"
                            type="email"
                            name="email"
                            className="form__input"
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="input__wrapper">
                        <input
                            placeholder="pass****"
                            type="password"
                            name="password"
                            className="form__input"
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                            register
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

home

```js
import React from "react";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function Home() {
    const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
    return (
        <Layout>
            <div>
                <h1>{user.fname}</h1>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

I am really confused so any advice will help.

Comment: This definitely needs to become a [mcve]. Not so much for us, but for you: start removing all those bits that don't matter, including pretty much all the routing, and even the content in that form. If it gets repeated, it'll still get repeated as a `<p>test</p>`.

Comment: The React Router API changed a lot between v5 and v6, so could you provide what version you are using of `react-router`?

Comment: @SaianshSingh i use v6

Comment: I don't see where the `Login` component is rendered in more than one place. Are you rendering it elsewhere in the code? Are you rendering the same JSX elsewhere in the code? What is the URL path when this rendering issue occurs?